# Spyder on Ubuntu 12.04 fails after trying to install ipython notebook

Tags: software-installation, python, spyder

Spyder IDE was working fine on both Ubuntu 12.04 in both laptops(HP mini & old Compaq Evo610c) After trying to install python notebook, Spyder stopped working. However Pyhton 2.7.3 works fine.
I noticed one sgment of Error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/pyhton2.7/dist-packages/path.py". line, 122, in *version*=pkg_resources.require('path.py')[0].version

so it expects /path.py under

> /usr/local/lib/pyhton2.7/dist-packages
>   There is no Spyder or spyder folder here

However there is a inside the path:

> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

the following folders: spyderlib and spyderplugins ....but NO 'path.py' file

I have re-installed spyder and purged it several times. Have tried re-intalation with Ubuntu Software Center, Synaptic Package Manager and command line. Same problem with pathway. No 'path.py' file installed.
 Thank you for any help and/or suggestions.

Comment: Is /usr/local/lib/py**ht**on2.7/dist-packages/path.py a typo?

Comment: This is probably a problem with your `setuptools` installation. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155633/error-while-starting-new-ipython-console-in-spyder).